# How to Update a Data in MySQL using Radio Button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon
Can I ask a question? but before that here is my code.

```
<html>
    <center>
    <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election2016");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Candidate Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Vote</th>
    <th>Number of Votes</th>
    </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid'/>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['NumberofVotes'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    <br>
    <br>
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "Update">
    </form>
    </center>
    </font>
    </html>
    <?php
             if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
                $dbhost = 'localhost';
                $dbuser = 'root';
                $dbpass = '';

                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                if(! $conn ) {
                   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                $candidateid = $row['candidateid'];


                $sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = '1' WHERE candidateid = $candidateid" ;
                mysql_select_db('election2016');
                $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                if(! $retval ) {
                   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";

                mysql_close($conn);
             }
    ?>
```

The Output of my Code Here is it will show list of Candidates,Position,Radio Button Number of Votes with a button save.

My error here is that when i select a radio button and click the button update i want to put 1 in numberofvotes field but its not updating. Whats wrong with my code?

Any help would be appreciated.
TY so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html>
        <center>
        <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election2016");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Candidate Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Vote</th>
        <th>Number of Votes</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['candidateid']."' >";
          echo "<td>" . $row['NumberofVotes'] . "</td>";
    $candidateid=$row['candidateid'];
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

        <br>
        <br>
        <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="candidateid" value="<?php echo $candidateid;?>">
         <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "update">
        </form>
        </center>
        </font>
        </html>
        <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    $dbhost = 'localhost';
                    $dbuser = 'root';
                    $dbpass = '';
 $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];
                    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                    if(! $conn ) {
                       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }

                    $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];


                    $sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'" ;
                    mysql_select_db('election2016');
                    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                    if(! $retval ) {
                       die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    echo "Updated data successfully\n";

                    mysql_close($conn);
                 }
        ?>
```

Comment: I checked this code and it's working. The problem is that you don't have the $row array when you post your form. So you have to send the id with a hidden field to the page. Thant's what I did to get your code work.

Comment: Sir I try the code but its not working. I get an error of undefined index

Comment: @AlexiusjoeCoronel Can you please show me your database structure? There is a mistake in the fieldnames you use in the code and one or more of the fieldnames in the code are not identical with the fieldnames in the database. The undefined index error is because of this.

Comment: table name candidate_info fields candidateid,candidatename,position,numberofvotes

Comment: Ok, On line 22 you wrote  echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>"; you should write  echo "<td>" . $row['candidatename'] . "</td>"; instead . Because as you see the name is you wrote it in camel case in your code but its lower case in your database. Undefined index occurs every time you try to access an array index which doesn't exists and in your case CandidateName doesn't exist.

Comment: Sir its already done and i fix it ty for the help i will approve your answer :)